# Python-How to set the font of Chinese character in table(ax,df)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of results,as shown below.

```
comment_corr=comment_book_content[['price','sale_num','sale_revenue','time_count','uid_num','vouch_count','comment_num']]
comment_corr.columns=[u'价格',u'销售数量',u'销售收入',u'总阅读时间',u'净用户数',u'兑换数',u'评论数',]
comment_corr_df=comment_corr.corr(method='pearson')
comment_corr_df=comment_corr_df.reset_index()
comment_corr_df
```

[image]

Now,I want to save this dataframe as a figure so I can put it in my remport. I tried the following method.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 3))
ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis
ax.set_title(u'书评图书各指标相关性分析',fontproperties=font,fontsize=15)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2, right=0.8, top=0.4,hspace=0.1,    wspace=0.3)
plt.tight_layout()

tabla=table(ax, comment_corr_df, rowLabels=  ['']*comment_corr_df.shape[0],colWidths=    [0.17]*len(comment_corr_df.columns),loc='center')  # where df is your data frame
tabla.auto_set_font_size(False) # Activate set fontsize manually
tabla.set_fontsize(10) # if fontsize is necessary ++colWidths
tabla.scale(1.6,1.8) # change size table
```

However,this `table` method can't successfully present Chinese characters,like the chinese character column names and row index as the shown below.
[image]

My question is how to set the font in the `table method,` so that it can normally show the Chinese characters in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You should an encoding clause at the beginning of your code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This should be the first line of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this method, but it does not  works